# How can I align vertically a smaller material float button?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, materialbutton

I have the following code to create some float buttons:

```html
    <div class='history-buttons__container'>
        <button mat-mini-fab>all</button>
        <button mat-mini-fab>1y</button>
        <button mat-mini-fab>6m</button>
        <button mat-mini-fab>30d</button>
    </div>
```

```css
.history-buttons__container > button{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
}
```

Which yields to the following:

[image]

If I removed the width and height they look ok:

[image]

As those elements are in an `diplay: block` to have them stacked vertically, I can not use `vertical-align`. What can I do to center the text inside the item while I make the icons smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With flex you can do it easily

```css
.history-buttons__container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
.history-buttons__container > button{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='history-buttons__container'>
        <button mat-mini-fab>all</button>
        <button mat-mini-fab>1y</button>
        <button mat-mini-fab>6m</button>
        <button mat-mini-fab>30d</button>
    </div>
```